# String split using regex with beginning >=|<=|=|<|>|\!= And a string plus incremental value

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have situation where I have to split the string in to 3 substrings.

Example

```
<=Mindate+30 >>> [<=,Mindate,+30]
<=Mindate  >>>  [<=,Mindate]
>=Maxdate-3 >>> [>=,Maxdate,-3]
==Date  >>>  [==,Date]
```

I have created a function that split current array in two

```
function splitString(str){  
var a= /(>=|<=|=|<|>|\!=)|.+/g
return str.match(a);
}
splitString('<=Mindate+45');
```

Current output ['<=', 'Mindate+45']
Expected output ['<=', 'Mindate', '+45']

Can any one help me on this ?

Comment: What's not working? What's the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just needed to separate the textual part (`\w+`) from the number part (`[-+]\d+`):

```js
function splitToThree(input) {
  let regex = /(>=|<=|==|<|>|\!=)|\w+|[-+]\d+/g;
  let ans = input.match(regex);
  console.log(ans);
}

splitToThree("<=Mindate+30");
splitToThree("<=Mindate");
splitToThree(">=Maxdate-3");
splitToThree("==Date");
```

Comment: regex can be written as `([><!=]=|[=<>]|\w+|[+-]\d+)`

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Thank you for your clarification. I assumed in this case the regex is more readable if the different cases are explicitly stated. In terms of efficiency your regex *is* probably better.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pattern that matches *and captures* all the comparison operators or matches a place before each of the `+`, `/`, `*` and `-` operators, and use the expression inside a `String#split` method:

```
a.split(/([<>!=]=|[=<>])|(?=[-+\/*])/).filter(Boolean)
```

See the JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['<=Mindate+30', '<=Mindate','>=Maxdate-3','==Date','>=SomeFn-3.45'];
rx = /([<>!=]=|[=<>])|(?=[-+\/*])/;
for (var a of strs) {
  var res = a.split(rx).filter(Boolean);
  console.log(a, "=>", res);
}
```

**Pattern details**

- `([<>!=]=|[=<>])` - Group 1 (this value will be part of the resulting array): `<`, `>`, `!`, `=` followed with `=` or a `=`, `<` or  `>` char
- `|` - or
- `(?=[-+\/*])` - a location that is followed with `-`, `+`, `/` or `*`.

Note: `.filter(Boolean)` will remove empty items from the resulting array.